# Make grid squares smaller instead of overflowing container

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm following TOP and I'm stuck on the etch-a-sketch project. Whenever I input a large number like 64 squares per side, the squares stay the same size and the grid extends off the page. I'd like for the squares to get smaller while the grid size remains the same. I've tried playing around with `overflow` `min-width`, `min-height`, and `minmax` but I can't get it right.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bar" style="text-align: center; margin: auto;">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// makes grid based on number of rows/cols entered
function drawGrid(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
  for (c = 0; c < rows * cols; c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  }
}

// deletes grid before reset
function deleteGrid() {
  let cell = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
  cell.forEach(cell => {
    container.removeChild(cell);
  });
}

// changes background color of divs to black
function etch() {
  let gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
  gridItems.forEach(gridItem => {
    gridItem.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
      gridItem.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    });
  });
}

drawGrid(16, 16);
etch();

// asks user how big they want the grid then calls delete and make functions
function reset() {
  let grid = prompt("How many squares per side?");

  deleteGrid();
  drawGrid(grid, grid);
}

// resets the grid when button is clicked
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
resetButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
  reset();
  etch();
});
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;
  max-height: 82vh;
  max-width: 82vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: On first blush it looks to me like the 1em padding might be the culprit.

Comment: Wow.. I can't believe that was the problem all along. Thank you so much! I've been reading guides and other questions for days trying to figure this out.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd write an answer but I think that's overkill for this, don't you? Glad, very glad, to help out. I've needed it many a time.

Comment: i would like to point out one thing and @Yishmeray include it in answer. **dont do such things directly with elemnts. its memory consuming. better use canvas. for easy coding use third prty library to play with canvas like threeJs**

Comment: @example You are very gracious.

Comment: @Yishmeray :) link to lib => https://threejs.org/